# Could not find diff-lcs when running generate rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundler, diff-lcs

I am a Django guy new to Rails.  I'm trying to get rspec-rails working for me but when I run

```
$ bundle exec rails generate rspec:install
```

I get..

```
Could not find diff-lcs-1.2.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Which is bothersome because

```
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
```

is alive and well in Gemfile.lock
I have deleted Gemfile.lock and rerun bundle to no avail.  I added gem 'diff-lcs' into my Gemfile too.

This is the way I have rspec rails in my gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

Any tips?

Comment: Do you get this same error with any `rails generate` command?  (I do.)

Comment: @user2642510: are you using any gemset? once check `gem list` whether you have installed `diff-lcs` gem or not and run bundle install again and try also check this link once http://pastebin.com/3eAHN76H

Answer (score 13):

Killing the `spring` processes took care of it for me, as described at https://jasonplayne.com/web-dev/rails-generate-could-not-find-in-any-of-the-sources.  I see that use of the spring loader was added in Rails 4.1, but I'm curious about the interaction here and what can be done to address this problem without having to kill spring.

Comment: cheers! This didn't fix the issue for me, but I did find out I had 8 spring servers running in the background sucking up resources.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your bundler:

```
$ gem update bundler
$ bundle install
```

Comment: I have the same symptom and this did not have any effect for me.  I'm running Bundler version 1.7.3